# Python loop through all possibilities of regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of strings that include some regular expressions-like strings that define **ALL** possible matches to form new strings. Example:

**Source**

```
Id[0-1][2-3]_Pos[1-3]
foo01_bar[A-C]
```

Is there any way in Python I can loop trough all possibilities and create new strings from it?
So, the example above shall deliver:

**Target**

```
Id02_Pos1
Id02_Pos2
Id02_Pos3
Id03_Pos1
Id03_Pos2
Id03_Pos3
Id12_Pos1
Id12_Pos2
Id12_Pos3
Id13_Pos1
Id13_Pos2
Id13_Pos3
foo01_barA
foo01_barB
foo01_barC
```

Any hints are welcomed.

**Update:**

A working example of the answer can be found here:  http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/invRegex.py

Comment: In the marked as duplicate question, the user asks for "ANY string that will match that regex", my question is for getting ALL strings that will match that regex.

Comment: Are you talking about "regex" here, or "regex-like strings in a very specific, limited notation"? If the former, how to loop through all the possibilities for `".*"`? If the latter, please clarify.

Comment: regex-like strings in a very specific, limited notation. The source will include mostly numbers [0-9].

Comment: So, the only "regex" element in your strings will be something like `[x-y]`, is this correct? No multiplicities, optional elements, lookaheads, backreferences, etc.?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The source is very basic and straight forward. The only possible options are: [0-9], [A-Z] and [a-z].

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing